# c# Calling c++ dll transfer struct array occurs exception

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

c++ header definition:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
#error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif
```

c++ function：

```
int Detect(Pos* pfps);
```

c++ struct definition：

```
struct FaceAngle
{
    int yaw;
    int pitch;
    int roll;
    float confidence;
};


typedef struct tagPOINT
{
    LONG x;
    LONG y;
}
POINT, * PPOINT, NEAR * NPPOINT, FAR * LPPOINT;


struct Pos
{
    RECT rcFace;
    POINT ptNose;
    FaceAngle fAngle;
    int nQuality;
    BYTE pFacialData[512];
    Pos()
    {
        memset(&rcFace, 0, sizeof(RECT));
        memset(&ptNose, 0, sizeof(POINT));
        memset(&fAngle, 0, sizeof(FaceAngle));
        nQuality = 0;
        memset(pFacialData, 0, 512);
    }
};
```

c++ Calling code:

```
void detect()
{
    Pos ptfp[10];
    Detect(ptfp);
}
```

===========================================================================

c# function definition:

```
[DllImport(THFaceDLLName, EntryPoint = "Detect")]
public static extern int Detect([In, Out] Pos[] posArray);
```

c# struct definition:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute    (System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential,
CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct Pos
{
    public RECT rcFace;
    public POINT ptNose;
    public FaceAngle fAngle;
    int nQuality;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 512)]
    byte[] pFacialData;
};


[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute    (System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet =     System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute    (System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet =     System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute    (System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet =     System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct FaceAngle
{
    int yaw;
    int pitch;
    int roll;
    float confidence;
};
```

c# calling code:

```
void detect()
{
   Pos[] facePosArray = new Pos[10];
   int faceNum = Detect(facePosArray);
}
```

An “System.AccessViolationException” exception occurs  after execution Detect function,
should i convert Pos[] to Intptr? can anyone has good solution

Comment: Depending if you are using Windows or Linux, the `sizeof(LONG)` could be different. Can you print from C++-side `sizeof(LONG)` and check if it is 4? And why the `Pack = 1`? Is there a `#pragma pack` c++-side?

Comment: Packing and calling convention look wrong. Why oh why can't we have a [mcve]. Almost every question on this topic falls down in that regard. If we had one it would be trivial to answer. Without one we can only guess.

Comment: POS contains pointers in c++.  The pointers are 4 bytes.  So in c# I usually use IntPtr as the type.  To fill the pointers in c# I use Marshal.StructureToPtr to convert manages structures to unmanaged memory.

Comment: @jdweng I don't see any pointer in `POS`... where do you see it? I see only an array, that in C is placed inside the structure

Comment: @jdweng No, no pointers in `POS`. Amazing that you keep on with this.

Comment: i will try to convert struct[] to intptr test,thank you all your people help

Comment: @chao No. Don't do that. That's a really bad idea. jdweng, sadly, has a history of giving out such bad advice. Clearly here he is wrong when he mentions pointers in a struct which contains none. Don't heed his advice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the struct contains "* PPOINT"  description

Comment: @chaochen No, it does not. The struct contains `POINT`. If you want help, provide a [mcve]. Then it will be trivial for someone that knows pinvoke to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you your advice,but the c++ code is Confidential，can't provide.

Comment: @chaochen Don't provide the confidential code. Construct a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. You don't need to return real data. Just populate the array with recognisable values and check that they find their way back to your C# program. That's a fundamental debugging skill that you would be advised to acquire.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tool that can directly convert c++ struct
such as:
[Software Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQhmM.png)

this is the download url:
    --download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe--